# How to get session data created by Auth0 in Ember.js 2.3

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth, auth0, ember.js-2

I am using Ember.js 2.3 (and Ember-Data 2.3). I'm setting up a simple user auth process using Auth0. Nothing fancy yet, just installed Auth0 according to:

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/ember2js/no-api

Now, my setup is pretty much exactly the same as the project given here. However, it seems that I can only access the session from application.hbs and not any other template. Or route. Or anything else.

So this handlebars snippet:

```
{{#if session.isAuthenticated}}
  {{session.data.authenticated.profile.name}}
{{else}}
  NOPE
{{/if}}
```

This works on application.hbs, but nowhere else. This does not make sense to me. If Auth0 itself says that session.data can be accessed from any template, and that such a handlebars snippet even exists, there must be something I'm missing. I need to be able to show certain portions of the client side as well as restrict some actions based on the currently signed-in user (and whether someone is actually signed in ), all of which are included in the session.data object.

It doesn't seem appropriate to pass this object to every component I'm going to create, and the only way I can think of getting this data right now is to manually get it from localStorage. I could perhaps make this manual process a mixin and have it included everywhere but before I try to find roundabout solutions, I want to make sure that I'm not missing something in the implementation itself.

How would I be able to access the session token throughout the application aside from application.hbs itself?

EDIT: Updating question in response to comments. My protected route looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
});
```

I am still unable to get session data, unfortunately.

Comment: You dont need to pass it. Just every time you want to use it you inject it with ```session: Ember.inject.service()```

Answer (score 0):

In ember-simple-auth session is a service which You need to inject to the other routes. So if you want to use the session data other than the application template, you need to extend those routes with AuthenticatedRouteMixin
(just like you did in routes/home.js). In controllers you need to inject the service, for example:

```
// app/controllers/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service('session')

  …
});
```

Take a look at [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth).
You can find another implementation if you check [ember-simple-auth-token](https://github.com/jpadilla/ember-simple-auth-token/blob/master/addon/authorizers/token.js)

**Edit:**
Try this in your routes/protected_route.js (it works for me)

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';
export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
  actions: {
    invalidateSession: function() {
      this.get('session').invalidate();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not working. I've updated the question with my protected route. Even with the authenticatedMixin, I cannot access the session. However, this route cannot be visited unless the user is correctly logged in, so I'm confident that the route somehow knows that the user is authenticated. I've tried injecting the service into the route itself to no avail. (I'm trying to move away from controllers as Ember is shifting to component based implementations).